# Can Cmd determine path location of a .exe or other file type?

Tags: windows, cmd, environment-variables, filepath

I think the best way to ask my question is by giving an example.
This is a question about environmental/user variables.
I am using windows system.
I have the environmental variable: `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts`
I have a file: `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`
typing "conda" into cmd opens `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe`

my question is:
What if i didn't know the file-path of `conda.exe`, is there a way for cmd to return:

```
"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe"
```

or return`"C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\"`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the command to find the location of an executable:

```
where conda.exe
```